# Is a Spring Data JPA @Query dynamic or named?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

JPA @NamedQuery is translated to SQL only once when application is deployed and generated SQL is cached.
EntityManager.createQuery translates query every time our method is called.

What Spring-data-jpa is doing with query defined in @Query annotation? Is it translated to SQL once during deployment (like NamedQuery) or translated every time (like dynamic query) ?

Comment: spring-data-jpa is not a JPA implementation so it won't be converting anything. Perhaps just looking at the log for the JPA implementation would answer that question for you ...

Comment: also, some JPA implementations cache the compiled query (i.e the SQL) so there is no such multiple translation. You don't mention what is your JPA implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Data JPA calls `EntityManager.createQuery(…)` for every invocation of a query method annotated with `@Query`. The reason for that is quite simple: the `Query` instances returned by the `EntityManager` are not thread-safe and actually stateful as they contain bound parameter information.

That said, most of the JPA persistence provider perform some kind of text-based query caching anyway so that they basically build the actual SQL query once for a certain JPQL query and reuse the former on subsequent invocations.

As an interesting side note, when we started building the support for `@Query` in 2008 we looked into possibilities to rather register the manually declared queries as named queries with JPA. Unfortunately there wasn't - and up until today - there's no way to manually register a named query programmatically via the JPA.